# Publish Go project dependencies to Jfrog Artifactory

Tags: go, devops, jfrog-cli

How can I load dependencies (based on go.mod) of a specific Go project in Jfrog Artifactory?. The project is loaded into the artifactory, but there is no dependency. I'm using local type artifactory

**Project**

```
super:
  |-- go.mod
  |-- go.sum
  |-- .jfrog
  |   `--projects
  |      `--go.yaml
  `-- pkg
      `--mega
         `--cool.go
```

**File: go.mod**

```
module super
go 1.19
require github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.9.2
require golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20220715151400-c0bba94af5f8 // indirect
```

**File: .jfrog/projects/go.yaml**

```
version: 1
type: go
resolver:
   repo: deps-super
   serverId: megaserver
deployer:
   repo: deps-super
   serverId: megaserver
```

**Publish steps**

```
cd ~/super
jfrog go-publish v1.2.3
```